# Quantity in checkout shopping cart doesn't work properly for Magento

Tags: ajax, magento, shopping-cart, magento-1.9, cart

I have use Magento 1.9.0.1 and on live server the cart is working correctly. I change the quantity of a product in the cart then I push the "Update cart" button and all works fine. I transferred the site another domain and the cart quantity doesn't work anymore. As I change the quantity of a product and click the button the quantity remains the same. If I go back and try to add the same product to the cart, even if I specify a different quantity like 10 and not 1, in the cart only 1 item is added every time I click on "add to the cart" button and not 10 as specified. I cannot figure out where's the problem. I excluded my custom theme and rolled back to the default theme and the problem persist. this site other functionality work fine.

Comment: check your logs for errors

Comment: Notice: Use of undefined constant tmp - assumed 'tmp'  in /lib/Zend/Cache.php on line 153

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like somewhere in your code you put `tmp` instead of `$tmp`. Run a search over all of your code for `tmp`. And Go through the function `getTmpDir` and check you have sufficient permission for `tmp` folder and access to write files in `tmp`.

Answer (score 0):

When i can change my magento local time zone. than this problem is solve.